# Titanium - <ul> and <li> aren't recognized by the html parser

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using an html parser for ios: https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.html2as.widget

and the html property for Android in a `Ti.UI.Label`

but the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags aren't recognized. Is it possible a solution?

Comment: Have you added this module : **https://github.com/FokkeZB/ti-html2as** before using this widget?

Comment: I think it's UL & LI are not supported tags.

Comment: Yes, I added the module ti-html2as..... and on iOS \n and \t aren't supported too?? I have problems with this tags too.

Comment: Can you show me some labels you like to add so that I can look for other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `ul` and `li` tags are not supported. Only the native functionality of Attributed String is supported. If you looked at the module it links to Attributed String page at the docs.

An attributed string guide can be found here and all included types: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Attributed_Strings

That said, I recommend using either a webview, or better StyledLabel. StyledLabel is a webview with stripped functionality. You can find the module here: https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.styledlabel

Then you can just set `html` as a property on the label instead of the `text` property.

**Even better** would be to prevent using HTML and not output HTML from the backend but instead the list itself as an array in a JSON response, and then visually build the page in the app.

Apps are not really build for HTML

Comment: Good description, and I think loading heavyweight HTML for light-weight elements is not a good idea at all.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes however the choice is not really there... and we have to live with HTML ;)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to create Android+iOS pie-charts, bars, graphs, etc.. in titanium?

I am asking this question because I have not been able to find the solid solution to these things other than creating them in HTML webview.

Comment: StyledLabel is a minimum html view, not attributed string. It has been "replaced" by Attributed String but this is not correct, it doesn't have the same set of functionality

Comment: I'm trying to do it in a webview, but on Android set the height is very difficult. Thank you.